# Magento 2 : How to programatically apply a condition on a coupon for specific product?

Tags: php-7, magento2.3.4, coupon

I want to apply a condition on a brand Product if the condition is true the coupon should not be applied.
Please Revert Asap!
THANK YOU!

Comment: How to apply coupons in your project? it's applied from the product page or cart page?

Comment: YUP! THANKS I HAVE FIXED THAT ISSUE Can you help me with the next Question which I have just now posted it will be a great help! Thanks once again!

Comment: If you managed to resolve your problem, do not hesitate to answer to your own question to provide information for the next visitors who are having a similar problem.